# Import multiple .mat files without headers

Tags: matlab

[image]

Currently trying to import the following via the following script:

```
files = dir('C:\Users\student\Desktop\pattern hw4\train\*.mat');

for i=1:length(files)
    A = load(files(i)); % <-- line 7
end
```

I get the error though:

```
Error using load
Argument must contain a string.

Error in hw4 (line 7)
    A = load(files(i));
```

After adding `.name` I get the error:

```
>> hw4
Error using load
Unable to read file 'class1_1.mat': no such file or directory.

Error in hw4 (line 7)
    A = load(files(i).name);
```

**Ok fixed and final answer/solution:**

```
files = dir('C:\Users\student\Desktop\pattern hw4\train\*.mat');

dname='C:\Users\student\Desktop\pattern hw4\train\';

for i=1:length(files)
    fname=fullfile(dname,files(i).name);
    A = load(fname);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load command is expecting the filename whereas dir returns a structure.  Try:

```
A = load(files(i).name);
```

Comment: It is a path issue now.  Try:` curpath= ''C:\Users\student\Desktop\pattern hw4\train\';  load(sprintf('%s%s',curpath,files(i).name);`

Comment: As you did help the original question, I'll mark this as the answer. The full solution is however posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `A = load(files(i).name);` at line 7.

`files` is an array of structs